# What is the third argument for inet_pton()?

Tags: c

my goal is to successfully call the function `inet_pton` in C.
I am using Windows 7. So far I learned that `inet_pton` has 3 arguments. Besides, its job is to translate human IP representation into binary representation for the computer.

Details on my understanding of the arguments of `inet_pton(a,b,c)`:

`a`: An address_family. For example AF_INET

`b`: A pointer to the human readable representation of the IP address (e.g."127.0.0.1").

`c`: A pointer to the "thing" where the translated IP address (binary form) is stored.

In a tutorial I read it is said `inet_pton` will store the translation inside the array c points to.

This page

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/cc805844(v=vs.85).aspx

tells me, that the third argument has the type `PVOID`.

```
INT WSAAPI inet_pton(__in   INT  Family,__in   PCTSTR pszAddrString,__out  PVOID pAddrBuf);
```

In my opinion the receiving array should be an char array. But `PVOID` is not equal to char.
The last idea I have is that a cast is involved, though I am only familiar with a cast in a situation like

```
buffer = (char*) malloc (i+1);
```

At the moment my code Looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *ptr2="127.0.0.1";
    char buffe[512];
    PVOID *ptr3;
    PVOID ptr3=&buffe;
    inet_pton(AF_INET,ptr2,ptr3);
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

How can I initialize the 3rd argument correctly (if it's necessary)? How to deal with the fact that the array storing the binary representation of the IP address should have the type **char** while the pointer should have the type `PVOID`?

My compiler is complaining about conflicting types for ptr3.
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Are you using a C++ compiler by accident? Conversions to and from `void *` don't require a cast in C.

Comment: Just curious, what is `InetPton` in `c`(in that particular CaSe)?

Comment: The page you linked says that the object pointed to by the third argument `pAddrBuf` must be large enough to hold one of two possible data structures, depending on the first argument. So I suggest you follow that page's links to those structure definitions.

Comment: @norum: I am using DEV C++. I believe it comes with a C++ compiler, but who knows^^

Comment: @Gosh: Can not tell you yet, because I have not yet successfully called inet_pton. so sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

`PVOID` is a *typedef* for `void *` which means that the third argument expects a generic pointer. `PCTSTR` is ultimately *typedef*ed to either `const char *` (if `UNICODE` is not defined) or `const wchar_t *` (if `UNICODE` is defined). See [Windows Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information on those specific types.

Instead of trying to figure out how many bytes to allocate using `malloc()` (hint: `sizeof(IN_ADDR)`), you can just directly use the data type it expects: [IN_ADDR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738571(v=vs.85).aspx). According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the third argument `pAddrBuf` needs to be large enough to hold an `IN_ADDR` when the first argument `Family` is `AF_INET`.

Try doing something like this:

```
#include <WinDef.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char ip_string[] = "127.0.0.1";
    IN_ADDR ip_value;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip_string, &ip_value);
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is the code supposed to not compile? Because I got an error message that there is an undefined reference to inet_pton.

Comment: @Heilmann I guessed at the includes from the documentation. I don't have a Windows machine to test the compilation. Try using the includes you provided in your question. Otherwise, ['inet_pton': identifier not found](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15660203/369450) might help.