# Why does WSAStringToAddress take a non-const AddressString?

Tags: winapi, parameters, constants, winsock2

The Windows documentation for [WSAStringToAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742214(v=vs.85).aspx) states:

```c
INT WSAAPI WSAStringToAddress(
  _In_     LPTSTR             AddressString,
  _In_     INT                AddressFamily,
  _In_opt_ LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFO lpProtocolInfo,
  _Out_    LPSOCKADDR         lpAddress,
  _Inout_  LPINT              lpAddressLength
);
```

`AddressString` an ***`_In_`*** parameter, and not an ***`_Inout_`*** parameter. Its not clear to me why the API takes a non-const pointer, and its causing a compile failure because I have a `const char*`.

My first question is, why does `WSAStringToAddress` take a non-const pointer?

My second question is, is it safe to cast the const-ness away? Will `WSAStringToAddress` modify the `char*` argument?

---

Here's more of the back story... I'm trying to use `WSAStringToAddress` in an `inet_addr` replacement due to deprecated warnings under contemporary versions of Visual Studio.

Here's the same problem detailed in a question with an [answer provided by Petar Korponaić](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660203/inet-pton-identifier-not-found/20816961#20816961). Korponaić experienced the same problem. Its the reason for the extra copy:

```c
int inet_pton(int af, const char *src, void *dst)
{
  struct sockaddr_storage ss;
  int size = sizeof(ss);
  char src_copy[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN+1];

  ZeroMemory(&ss, sizeof(ss));
  /* stupid non-const API */
  strncpy (src_copy, src, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN+1);
  src_copy[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = 0;

  if (WSAStringToAddress(src_copy, af, NULL, (struct sockaddr *)&ss, &size) == 0)
  ...
}
```

Comment: There are some Windows apis - and this may or may not be one of them - that modify strings in place - for example to add a terminating zero to use a string fragment with an api that expects a zero terminated string, and then restoring the overwritten character. If you just cast away the constness you can introduce race conditions or an exception if the source string is a literal stored in read only memory.

Comment: @ChrisBecke: Those parameters are attributed using one of the `_Inout_` SAL annotations (like the *lpCommandLine* parameter in [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx)). In this case, however, there is an `_In_` annotation. Since SAL annotations are evaluated both at the call site as well as the implementation, I would assume, that *AddressString* can be a constant. I wouldn't think that the deployed *Ws2_32.dll* binary compiles with warnings (or has certain SAL warnings disabled), although I haven't reverse engineered the code.

Answer (score 0):

1. The Windows is a C API, thus C strings defined as `"Some string"` are not constant. C++ changes that by making them constant.
2. Yes it is perfectly safe to cast away the constness using `const_cast<LPTSTR>("my string").`

Comment: You can only cast away const if the object is non-const. An example of undefined behavior is, `const char site[] = "www.google.com";` followed by `WSAStringToAddress(site, ...)`. The const cannot be cast away because the object is const. Also see [Is it safe to remove const via const_cast and invoke a non-const function that does not modify the resulting object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29883327/608639)